# html <textarea> not resetting properly using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple comment form which consists of a textfield for name and a textarea for the comment and a regular button for submitting. The submit button resets the textarea per the jquery below. It works fine except one annoying issue, if I write something and press enter it removes the text from the textarea but creates a new line in the textarea. How do i fix it so the textarea is truly empty when pressing enter?

It is also on codepen: http://codepen.io/erikL/pen/Leymj

HTML

```
<p class="inline-block name">Name</p>&nbsp

<input type="text" placeholder="Your name" id="userName" maxlength="30">
    <textarea class="comment" id="userComment" placeholder="Enter your comment here" maxLength="300"></textarea>

    <p><em>max 300 characters</em></p>

    <input type="button" class="comment" value="Submit" onclick="userComment()" id="button" />

<div id="comments"></div>
```

Javascript for submitting comment

```
function userComment() {
  var textd = document.getElementById("userComment");
  var named = document.getElementById("userName");
  var textdVal = textd.value;
  var namedVal = named.value;

  if (namedVal.length < 1) {
    alert('Please enter you name.');
  }
  else {
    if(textdVal.length < 3) {
      textdVal = 'No comment.';
    }
  var namedParagraph = document.createElement('p');
  var textdParagraph = document.createElement('p');
  namedParagraph.textContent = namedVal + (' - ') + date;
  textdParagraph.textContent = textdVal;
  namedParagraph.className = 'commentName';
  textdParagraph.className = 'commentText';

  document.getElementById("comments").appendChild(namedParagraph);
  document.getElementById("comments").appendChild(textdParagraph);

  document.getElementById("userName").value=""; //this is where it resets the name
  document.getElementById("userComment").value=""; //this is where it resets the comment
  }
};
```

Jquery for resetting the form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userComment').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13) 
      $('#button').click();
    });
});
```

I do apologize if the question is unclear or lacking information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From a UX standpoint, will this functionality confuse people? If I were typing something in the textarea, I wouldn't expect hitting return to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `e.preventDefault()` to your `keypress` handler's conditional.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Avzaq

Comment: Thank you! Easy solution that works just as planned.

Comment: @LarryG, One suggestion after press ENTER on textarea focus should be moved in CommnetName textbox.

Answer (score 0):

this is solution... e.preventDefault();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#userComment').keypress(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     if(e.keyCode==13) 
     $('#button').click();
  });
});
```